# Unix: Is there a way to "copy" file or directory permissions?

Tags: unix, permissions, file-management

I have two files in a directory. One has correct permissions and the other has not. Is there a way I can "copy" the set of permissions from one file to another?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The GNU version of the *chmod* utility can [copy the mode](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) from one file (`RFile`) to another (`file`).

```
chmod --reference=RFile file
```

[GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) is found in most Linux distributions and Cygwin, among other places.  [Not all *chmod* implementations](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chmod.html) provide this option.

Comment: Hm... looks like this is supposed to work, but not supported on Mac OS X? There I only get illegal option...

Comment: *chmod* is not a *bash* builtin command.  it is a separate utility available on many unixes.  the `--reference` option is included in the GNU version; OSX probably uses a *chmod* that originates with BSD instead.  OSX *man chmod* : http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chmod.1.html

Comment: Svish, you might consider installing the GNU versions through MacPorts.

Comment: Just figured that it would be useful to mention here that `cp -dpR <source-file> <dest-file>` will, when copying a file, copy permissions as well as the file.r

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this:

```
find $SOURCE -mindepth 1 -printf 'chmod --reference=%p\t%p\n'|sed "s/\t$SOURCE/ $DEST/g"|sh
```

It is not fully bullet proof, but does what I need.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

`find /PATH/TO/TARGET -exec chmod --reference /PATH/TO/SOURCE/{} {} \;`

this would go up recursivly and chmod every file, if two directory don't match on files you will see lots of "No such file or directory" error.

Comment: `find /home/myubuntuuser/Desktop/test1 -exec chmod --reference /home/myubuntuuser/Desktop/test2/{} {} \;`

Comment: chmod: failed to get attributes of '/home/myubuntuuser/Desktop/test2//home/myubuntuuser/Desktop/test1': No such file or directory
chmod: failed to get attributes of '/home/myubuntuuser/Desktop/test2//home/myubuntuuser/Desktop/test1/111.txt': No such file or directory
chmod: failed to get attributes of '/home/myubuntuuser/Desktop/test2//home/myubuntuuser/Desktop/test1/222.txt': No such file or directory
chmod: failed to get attributes of '/home/myubuntuuser/Desktop/test2//home/myubuntuuser/Desktop/test1/333.txt': No such file or directory

Comment: tested it on 2 folders: test1 and test2. each have the same files 111/222/333.txt with different permissions. test1 has the default ones. test2 has 777 permissions.
this is the error i get.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getfacl` to retrieve the full listing of file permissions, owner, group, and additional ACLs (access control lists).

```
$ getfacl filename.txt
# file: filename.txt
# owner: score
# group: score
user::rw-
group::---
other::---
```

If you save that output to a file (e.g. `acl.txt`), you can then restore from this format with `setfacl --restore acl.txt`. If you only want to restore a single file, and that file has a different filename to the original, you will want to use `setfacl --set-file acl.txt filename.txt` (where `filename.txt` is the new filename).

### Steps

1. Save original permissions to `acl.txt`:

   ```
   $ getfacl filename.txt > acl.txt
   ```
2. Overwrite permissions (for demonstration; this is just so that you can see that restoring it in the next step works)

   ```
   $ chmod 777 filename.txt
   $ sudo chown nobody:root filename.txt
   $ ls -l filename.txt
   -rwxrwxrwx 1 nobody root 0 Jan  8 14:24 filename.txt
   ```
3. Use `setfacl` to restore correct permissions from `acl.txt`:

   ```
   $ sudo setfacl --restore acl.txt
   $ ls -l filename.txt
   -rw------- 1 score score 0 Jan  8 14:24 filename.txt
   ```

The filename is taken from the `# file:` comment generated by `getfacl`, so there is no need to specify it on the command line.

If you want to restore those permissions to a different file, you can use `--set-file` instead of `--restore` like so:

```
$ setfacl --set-file acl.txt second_filename.txt
```

### Example

If you end up overwriting the permissions on some files in `/usr`, but you don't know what files you have overwritten, you can usually fix it by restoring from another similarly configured system.

1. Backup permissions from working system (note: `getfacl` generates relative paths, so ensure you `cd` to a consistent location on both machines)

   ```
   # cd /
   # getfacl -R usr > /root/acls.txt
   ```
2. Copy the ACL dump to the system with broken permissions

   ```
   $ scp root@working-system:/root/acls.txt .
   $ scp acls.txt root@broken-system:/root/
   ```
3. Restore the ACL dump to overwrite the broken permissions with those from the known good machine

   ```
   # cd /
   # setfacl --restore /root/acls.txt
   ```