# Clone permissions for all files in a folder

Tags: chmod

I have a question. So I have 2 folders, both of which have the same files in them, but some with different content, but the same names. What I want to do is clone all of the file permissions from one folder, into the permissions for another folder. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [Unix: Is there a way to "copy" file or directory permissions?](https://superuser.com/questions/114558/unix-is-there-a-way-to-copy-file-or-directory-permissions) .

You can achieve this by typing this:

```
chmod --reference=RFile file
```

Comment: Could I use -R to do it to all files in the dir?

Comment: I am on my phone, can't try right now, but you should probably be able to. Otherwise, you could make a script that would recurse into subdirectories and do this for all the files.

Comment: It didnt seem to do it to recursively... I ran `chmod -R --reference=/home/tcagame_svc4/karl/4/garrysmod/ /home/tcagame_svc7/stefen/7/garrysmod/`

Comment: Good idea by Tiago CA, maybe you should provide an asterisk after the slash, without specifying -R.

Comment: Tiago CA's answer doesn't work for me, but this does: `for i in foo/*; do j=$(basename $i); chmod bar/$j --reference foo/$j; done` (you want to copy the permissions from `foo` to `bar` and they are flat directories).

Comment: @PauloAlmeida What do you mean by "flat" the directories have more than 1 directory inside of them.

Comment: By 'flat' I meant with no subdirectories. If there are subdirectories the script will be more complex.

Comment: Hmmm... Is there a simple way to do it? @PauloAlmeida

Comment: If you want to copy the permissions in `bar` to `foo`, go into `bar` and type this: `find . -exec chmod --reference={} ../foo/{} \;` (this assumes `foo` and `bar` are at the same level; if not, adjust the path in the `exec` command).

Answer (score -1):

This seems work for me:

```
$ sudo chmod --reference foo/ baz/*
```

Comment: On my system (coreutils 8.13) that copies the permissions from the `foo` directory to each file in `bar`.