# How to copy file/folder permissions and ownerships from one folder to an other (recursively)

Tags: permissions, git, file-permissions, clone

How do I copy all the folder, subfolders and files permissions (recursively) from `/www_03062018` to my new `/www` ?

I came across this post: [Clone permissions for all files in a folder](https://superuser.com/questions/625673/clone-permissions-for-all-files-in-a-folder)

```
chmod --reference=RFile file
```

Which didn't help much, it did apply a change for the main folder `/www` but didn't apply on its subfolders and files.

i have tried:

```
chmod -R --reference=/www_03062018 /www
```

and it didn't work.

**My situation:**

I have 2 folders on my Ubuntu machine: `/www` and `/www_03062018`.

`/www` is a "git clone" from the production machine.

`/www_03062018` is my old directory that i used to work on and upload files via FTP.

I started to use GIT and when I clone a directory - all its folder ownerships and file accesses settings doesn't get cloned too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> cd /www
> find . -path ./.git -prune -or -exec chmod --reference '/www_03062018/{}' '{}' \; -exec chown --reference '/www_03062018/{}' '{}' \;
> ```

retrieved and adapted from [here](https://superuser.com/a/1283574/572794)

Comment: tested it on 2 folders: test1 and test2. each have the same files 111/222/333.txt with different permissions. test1 has the default ones. test2 has 777 permissions. this is the error i get.

Comment: find /home/myubuntuuser/Desktop/test1 -exec chmod --reference /home/myubuntuuser/Desktop/test2/{} {} \;

Comment: chmod: failed to get attributes of '/home/myubuntuuser/Desktop/test2//home/myubuntuuser/Desktop/test1': No such file or directory chmod: failed to get attributes of '/home/myubuntuuser/Desktop/test2//home/myubuntuuser/Desktop/test1/111.txt': No such file or directory chmod: failed to get attributes of '/home/myubuntuuser/Desktop/test2//home/myubuntuuser/Desktop/test1/222.txt': No such file or directory chmod: failed to get attributes of '/home/myubuntuuser/Desktop/test2//home/myubuntuuser/Desktop/test1/333.txt': No such file or directory

Comment: right, I made a mistake. I needed relative paths.

Comment: (I edited my post)

Comment: weird, testing it on the desktop with the 2 folders i created - this works. but with /www it doesn't `Operation not permitted` so i usered `sudo find . -path ______ ect` and it gets me a lot of `No such file or directory`

Comment: Does it work for files that exists in both directories?

Comment: Yes, works both directions, but doesn't work on my /www directory with both errors menthined. I tried it again after logging in as `sudo su`.. still same result

Comment: Sorry my bad, this works. I just looked and the owners of the folders/files and didn't notice the permissions. 
I tried the same command with `chown` and i got the ownership right too. thanks a lot